# Is there a high probability bound of quadratic forms?

Tags: probability, linear-algebra, probability-inequalities, quadratic-form, norm

I am wondering about the following: For a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and vector $x \in [-1,1]^n$, if $X$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that w.h.p. $X_i \not\in [-1,1] \; (\forall i)$ does it then hold with high probability that $x^\top A^2 x = \|A x\|_2^2 \leq \|A X\|_2^2 = X^\top A^2 X$?
Intuitively, I am thinking that this should be true because w.h.p. $X$ has (pointwise) more "extreme" values than $x$.

Comment: What is "w.h.p."?

Comment: @paperskilltrees I suspect it is [with high probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_high_probability).

Comment: @Galen it is with high probability with high probability

Comment: Take $n=2$,  $x^\top A^2 x = (x_1 - x_2)^2$ and  $X_1 = X_2$ with $X_i$ being standard Pareto and $x = [-1, \,1]$. We have $x^\top A^2 x = 4$ and  $X^\top A^2 X = 0$ with probability one.

Comment: Thanks @Yves! I see now that this does not hold.